# Anyone had success with IDA & Windroye/Andydroid/BlueStacks?

Tags: ida, android

Has anyone had luck debugging JNI code inside of an Android Emulator using IDA?  I haven't been able to get any of the popular Windows Android emulators to work.  Been trying step such as in http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2050393&nocache=1 but can't get android_server to launch.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot debug native code with those emulators as they aren't arm based. The emulator from google will however work.

For example BlueStacks uses a proprietary technology called LayerCake which allows apps to run at near native speeds. This is possible since LayerCake *"converts"* ARM to x86 and this is the reason for its speed.